# Data returned from the controller is not showing in the template file

Tags: 8, theming

I am sending data from a custom module controller to a template file using the following code.

#### module.info.yml

```
name: Module
description: Module description
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

#### module.module

```
function module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'module_template' => [
      'variables' => [
        'var' => [],
        'title' => ''
      ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

#### module.routing.yml

```
module.event:
  path: '/path/{dynamic}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\controller::RunQuery'
    _title: 'Module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### module-template.html.twig

```
<p> test {{ title }}</p>
<ul>
{% for user in var %}
  <li> {{ user.title }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
test 2
```

#### controller.php

```
namespace Drupal\module;

class controller {

  public function RunQuery($dynamic) {

    // Some query here which work fine and return what I want
    $ok = 'Some value';

    return [
      '#theme' => 'module_template',
      '#var'   => $ok,
      '#title' => 'Title',
    ];
  }

}
```

This will return only *test* and *test 2* in the template file, so the template file is called by the module controller, but it does not show `{{ title }}` and `{{ user.title }}`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do as `var` never seems to be passed an array or object but I'll give you a working example. Your controller should extend `ControllerBase` and use `public function content()` to output stuff. Also pay attention to reference the correct `namespace` and pay attention to upper and lower case writing as well.

**module.info.yml**

```
name: Module
description: Module description
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
```

**module.module**

```
function module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'module_template' => [
      'variables' => [
        'var'   => NULL,
        'title' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

**module.routing.yml**

```
module.event:
  path: '/path/{user}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\Controller::content'
    _title: 'Module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**templates/module-template.html.twig**

```
<p> test {{ title }}</p>
<div>{{ var.getUsername }}</div>
test 2
```

**src/Controller/Controller.php**

```
namespace Drupal\module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

class Controller extends ControllerBase {

  public function content(AccountInterface $user) {

    return [
      '#theme' => 'module_template',
      '#var'   => $user,
      '#title' => 'Title',
    ];
  }

}
```

---

Now you can access `/path/1` or whatever user ID you want to get this user's name printed.

With the Devel sub-module Kint installed you can use `{{ kint() }}` or `{{ kint(var) }}` inside the template to check out what else you can get and print.